# Connect to netcat listener from inside of the QEMU system

Tags: linux, shell, qemu, netcat, reverse-shell

I have `.cpio` file containing a filesystem that is loaded as `initrd` for a QEMU emulation. Here's the `run.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh
qemu-system-arm \
    -m 1024 \
    -M virt,highmem=off \
    -kernel zImage \
    -initrd filesystem.cpio \
    -nic user,hostfwd=tcp:0.0.0.0:8080-:80
    -nographic
```

Since I want to spawn a reverse shell, I statically compiled one and included it in the `/bin` folder of the decompressed filesystem. The executable is trying to establish a TCP connection with `10.0.2.2:4242` (which I saw is QEMU's gateway address), and then launch a `/bin/bash`.
This is the code for my revshell:

```
int main(void) {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

    printf("Launching reverse shell...\n");

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        perror("Socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(4242);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.2.2");

    printf("Trying to connect to %s on port %d...\n", inet_ntoa(serv_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(serv_addr.sin_port));

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0) {
        perror("Connection with the server failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Connected successfully. Executing shell...\n");

    dup2(sockfd, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(sockfd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(sockfd, STDERR_FILENO);

[etc...]
```

To execute the reverse shell, I modified the `init` file accordingly and compressed everything back.
This is the `init` file:

```
#!/bin/busybox ash
/bin/busybox mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
/bin/busybox mount -t proc  proc /proc
/bin/busybox mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /dev
/bin/busybox mkdir -p /dev/shm
/bin/busybox mkdir -p /dev/pts
/bin/busybox mount -t devpts devpts /dev/pts
/bin/busybox mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug
# Populate /dev according to /sys
/bin/busybox mknod -m 660 console c 5 1
/bin/busybox mknod -m 660 null c 1 3
/bin/busybox mdev -s
/bin/busybox --install -s
echo "Welcome!" > /dev/console
/bin/reverseshell &
exec /sbin/init "$@" </dev/console >/dev/console 2>&1
```

As you can see I already have a console that spawns as soon as the virtualization starts, but it's full of junk and QEMU errors, that's why I need a reverse shell.

Then, I set up a netcat listener over the 4242 port via `nc -lnvp 4242`.

However, when launching the `run.sh` script, I end up with the following errors:

```
...
[    1.001342] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2048K
[    1.007212] Run /init as init process
Welcome!
Launching reverse shell...
Trying to connect to 10.0.2.2 on port 4242...
Connection with the server failed: Network is unreachable
...
```

And no connection received by the listener on my host.
I am pretty noob with QEMU, and I do not know many of its features.
Can you help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance :)